# Rails confirmation pop-up appears multiple times

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a delete button for my view. When I try to delete an entity, confirmation message appears three times. I have checked the location of "javascript_include_tag" and it is in the head section.

```
<%= link_to activity_path(activity), method: :get, :id => "button", :class => "btn btn-info btn-sm btn-icon icon-left" do %>
 <i class="entypo-info">
</i>Show <% end %>
```

And this is my application.js

```
//= require jquery-1.11.0.min
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require main-gsap
//= require jquery-ui-1.10.3.minimal.min.js
//= require bootstrap
//= require joinable
//= require resizeable
//= require neon-api
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js
//= require jquery.sparkline.min
//= require d3.v3
//= require rickshaw.min
//= require raphael-min
//= require morris.min
//= require toastr
//= require neon-custom
//= require neon-chat
//= require neon-demo
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix your issue but I did notice you have a "do" at the end of this line that seems out of place: <%= link_to activity_path(activity), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'are    you sure?'}, :id => "button", :class => "btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-icon icon-left" do %>. You would be missing some content and an <% end %>

Comment: actually that "do" is for icon. there is full code;                                         <%= link_to activity_path(activity), method: :get, :id => "button", :class => "btn btn-info btn-sm btn-icon icon-left" do %>
                <i class="entypo-info"></i>Show                                              <% end %>

Comment: Yes, see the end of my comment, "You would be missing some content and an <% end %>". You should post that full code into your post just so we know it's not missing.

Comment: The other thing I noticed is that you're including both jquery and jquery.min--you only really need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a basic mistake and I found the problem in my code. "javascript_include_tag" was used in my index.html.erb and also application.html.erb. This duplication caused javascript to run multiple times and confirmation pop-up to appear several times.